# How to calculate complex Fourier coefficient?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, mathematical-physics

Consider a step function $u:[0,1] \to R $ where R is the real numbers 
  $$ u(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $u<1$} \\
1, & \text{if $u\ge 1$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
Determine the complex Fourier coefficients $u_j$ s.t. $$u(x)= \sum_{-\infty}^\infty u_je^{2\pi jix} $$ 
Note that $$ u_j = \int_0^1 u(x)e^{-2\pi jix}dx$$
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$u_j= \frac{e^{-\pi ji}-e^{2\pi ji}}{2\pi ji} = -\frac{i}{2\pi j}(\cos(-\pi j) + i\sin(-\pi j) - \cos(2\pi j) - i\sin(2\pi j)) = \cdots$$

Comment: How does that help me, because they have different powers?

Comment: @marocaine, sorry. I missed the 2.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/722471)

Comment: @Henrik, seriously? The *hint* was good.

Comment: @marocaine Can you simplify each of the four terms on the right hand side?

Comment: @marocaine, use the periodicity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you bound to demonstrate it with Fourier series or you can use Fourier transformation? If the second option is possible, take a look just to time domain shifting property plus step Fourier transformation

Edit: do you know how to define a sin as complex number? 
 sin(z) = ( exp(i*z) - exp(-i*z))/(2*i) 
Just try to define your uj as it ...